# Simplify powers of Kronecker deltas

Tags: simplifying-expressions

I have produced an expression in Mathematica that depends on various `KroneckerDelta`s and powers thereof. Naturally I would have thought that expressions that look like

$$ \delta_{i,j}^2$$

would be simplified to $\delta_{i,j}$, since $\delta_{i,j}$ only takes value 0 or 1. Instead the expression stays as is despite using `FullSimplify`.

`FullSimplify[KroneckerDelta[i,j]^2]` outputs $ \delta_{i,j}^2$.

Is there a way to do this simplification in a big expression without manually inputting an assumption like $ \delta_{i,j}^2== \delta_{i,j}$?

Comment: `Reduce[KroneckerDelta[i, j]^2 == KroneckerDelta[i, j]]` gives `True`

Comment: Yes, that tells me Mathematica knows, but given a big expression containing many powers of the deltas, how do I simplify it?

Comment: @user2723984, it will be helpful if you provide an example of such expression. You can use `Reduce` or also manually write replacement rules and use `ReplaceAll`/`ReplaceRepeated`.

Comment: `expr /. (KroneckerDelta[i_, j_]^n_Integer?Positive) :> KroneckerDelta[i, j]`

Comment: This https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/287523/product-involving-kronecker-deltas/287532#287532 might be of use to you.